# pass 2d array from ruby to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I want to pass a 2d array from ruby to javascript.

I currently have this id in the view:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= @statistics %>);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

@statistics is a 2d array comin from the controller

Answer (score 3):

The method you are looking for is `#to_json`.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= @statistics.to_json %>);
```

For example:

```
[["abc", 123], ["def", 456]].to_json # => [["abc",123],["def",456]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]].to_json # => [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

If your `@statistics` variable is not a plain 2D array, it may require additional processing before you output it to JSON.

Comment: It does not work, It gives me a blank page. My array should be something like that : [['task', 'points'], ['A', 20]]

Comment: What is the code that generates your `@statistics` array? If you run the code in your `rails console`, what is the output?

Comment: I just have this in the console : @statistics = [['task', 'points'], ['A', 20]]

Comment: `[['task', 'points'], ['A', 20]].to_json` gives me `[["task","points"],["A",20]]`, so it looks like there is something else going on. Can you post the exact controller and view code you are using?